# Duvida quanto ao upload de imagem

Tags: php, upload

estou usando uma classe de upload em php, na verdade está tudo funcionando, consigo fazer o upload normal e exibir, mas quando entro na respectiva pasta dentro do projeto os arquivos não estão lá.

Ja coloquei pra vizualizar arquivos ocultos nada aparece, 
Ja utilizei o CMD pra listar o conteudo da pasta e nada,
Não estou salvando em banco de dados,
Já procurei dentro da classe se existe alguma referencia que crie o arquivo em modo oculto e nada.
Queria uma ajuda pra saber onde esses arquivos vão parar. Nunca Vi Isso.... fazer upload e o arquivo não ficar em lugar nenhum, e mesmo assim funcionar normalmente chamando a url corretamente... já olhei ate no meu pc...

Uso esta Classe de Upload

> https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof

arquivo php que instancia a classe e configura a forma de envio e etc...

```
if($image["pictures"]){
    $image->setLocation(__DIR__ . "\usuarios");
    $upload = $image->upload();
    if($upload){
        echo "<img src='http://sdspot.com.br/suporte/upload/usuarios/".$upload->getName().".".$image->getMime()."' alt=''>";
        echo $upload->getFullPath();
    }else{
        echo $image->getError();
    }
}

?>
```

Arquivo que manda o arquivo de imagem

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="Upload.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000"/>
    <input type="file" name="pictures" accept="image/*"/>
    <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

IMG - 1 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
IMG - 2 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
IMG - 3 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Olá, pelo que vi do seu código e da Classe de upload, acredito que esta no diretório usuarios do seu computador! Já verificou? Quando eu crio um diretório para imagens em aplicações eu crio um dedicado por exemplo imgs_produtos e salvo tudo lá e no banco de dados eu só salvo o nome do arquivo e sua extensão

Comment: Meu sistema esta assim, Servidor apache em um servidor na rede, se estivesse na minha maquina somente eu poderia ver o arquivo usando a URL, mas em qualquer maquina da rede consegue ver usando o endereco sdspot.com.br

Comment: Olá, bom acredito então que esteja nesta pasta do servidor dentro da rede! Acredito que a propria classe aponte pro diretorio usuarios dentro do servidor

Comment: pois é, elas aparecem no navegador apenas, mas se eu abro a pasta onde ela esta não aparece nada...

Comment: Nossa, nunca vi nada parecido! Desculpe por não conseguir ajudar